Creating a Dataset directly from a Kaggle Notebook
Can anyone really explain in lay man's terms hoe this can actually be done.
I just created a working notebook that outputs a csv file into the /kaggle/working directory and it gets updated with a timestamp every time I run it.
df.to_csv(f'/kaggle/working/CMC_24h_Gainers_Starting_07_10_24 updated - {timestamp}.csv',mode='a', header=False, index=False)#To append to the list
Now I want to make that csv a dataset for the public.
I do not quite understand the use of the kaggle api.
Is this the only way or there's another?
Thanks!

Inside a notebook, you can create a dataset using the Kaggle API; following the steps:
### Create Kaggle Dataset

os.makedirs(SAVE_FOLDER, exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs(SAVE_FOLDER + '/folder_name_placeholder/', exist_ok=True)

with open('../input/kaggle-secrets/kaggle.json') as f:
    kaggle_creds = json.load(f)
    
os.environ['KAGGLE_USERNAME'] = kaggle_creds['username']
os.environ['KAGGLE_KEY'] = kaggle_creds['key']

!kaggle datasets init -p '{SAVE_FOLDER}'

with open(f'{SAVE_FOLDER}/dataset-metadata.json') as f:
    dataset_meta = json.load(f)
    
dataset_meta['id'] = f'username_placeholder/{DATASET_NAME}'
dataset_meta['title'] = DATASET_NAME

with open(f'{SAVE_FOLDER}/dataset-metadata.json', "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(dataset_meta, outfile)


!cp '{SAVE_FOLDER}'/dataset-metadata.json '{SAVE_FOLDER}'/meta.json
!ls '{SAVE_FOLDER}'

!kaggle datasets create -u -p '{SAVE_FOLDER}'

Then writing the data in the folder you created via eg.
df.to_csv(f'{SAVE_FOLDER}/folder_name_placehoder/CMC_24h_Gainers_Starting_07_10_24 updated - {timestamp}.csv',mode='a', header=False, index=False)

and finally resuming the dataset creation:
!kaggle datasets version -m {version_name} -p "{SAVE_FOLDER}"  -r tar -r zip

